# Initializing Arrays with a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to get an array to be initialized in a function. The initialized array should contain a set of random numbers within a certain range when working as intended. Is this possible in C?

Comment: Yes it is. Please expand on your question if you want any further assistance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The short answer to your first question is: "Yes, it's possible." However, if you want further help, then you should show us some sign of the effort you've made so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <time.h>  //time func for seed init
 #include <stdlib.h> //srand/rand funcs
 #include <stdio.h>  //Library for printf function
 #define LIMIT 100 

 void myFunction(int array[], int arrayIndexMaxSize){
     for (int index = 0; index < arrayIndexMaxSize; index++){
         array[index] = rand() % LIMIT;   //Where limit is randomly produced from 0 - Limit inclusive
         printf("array[%d] of arrayIndexMaxSize(%d) = %d\n", index, arrayIndexMaxSize, array[index]);  //prints out th$
     }
 }

 void main(){
     srand(time(0));  //initializes kinda random number generator
     int array[50]; //If known at runtime or compile time, must be at block scope meaing inside {curly} braces of any$
     myFunction(array, 50);
 }
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that it is disputable if such requests as from the OP should be fulfilled, you could at least provide a clean c program (i.e. one that compiles, preferably without warnings).

Comment: Small caveat: `rand() % LIMIT` is almost always unevenly distributed (although the effect is minimal with a rather small `LIMIT`).

Comment: Good point, I didn't bother to check it before hand...it was a bit sloppy!

Comment: `myFunction(array)` and `myFunction(&array[0])` both pass an `int *` and are the same, but `myFunction(&array)` passes an `int **`.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Neil - `myFunction(&array)` will pass an `int (*)[50]`, not an `int **` -- very different

Comment: I would suggest not to use the value `50` (for the array size) twice in the code, but rather define a constant for it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd that's very true. Good call.